# Sub-setting a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, rows

I have a matrix like:

```
1 2 3 4 5

2 3 4 6 7

3 3 5 7 0

4 9 2 4 5
```

now I want to extract rows with number "3" in the second column, and get them together, like this:

```
2 3 4 6 7

3 3 5 7 0
```

How can I do it in R? Sorry i'm a greenhorn in R.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff that could have easily been found with a quick search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data:

```
mydata<-c(1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,6,7,3,3,5,7,0,4,9,2,4,5)
mat<-matrix(mydata,ncol=5, byrow=T)
mat

#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    2    3    4    6    7
#[3,]    3    3    5    7    0
#[4,]    4    9    2    4    5
```

use

```
mat[mat[,2]==3,]
```

result being:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    3    4    6    7
[2,]    3    3    5    7    0
```

Comment: @RichardScriven good point, edited as appropriate

Comment: thank you. this works perfect. But when I apply this method to my research problem which is about dealing with a 6720*23 double matrix, it does not work. the result only shows the first row desired. i don't know why.